# SQL Error Msg 8120 Fix

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I'm having some troubles figuring out where my error is here. This is the question:

```
Write a SELECT statement that returns the following columns
a. ShipmentOrderDate
b. Clients Email Address
c. Column that calculates the Total Order called OrderTotal
d. A Column that uses the Rank() function to return a column named OrderTotalRank that
ranks the Order Total in Desc Order.
e. A column that uses the DenseRank() function to return a column called DenseRank that
ranks the Order Total in Desc Order.
```

And this is what I have coded:

```
SELECT ShipmentOrderDate, EmailAddress,
    SUM(sh.ShipItemPrice * sh.Quantity) AS OrderTotalRank,
    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(sh.ShipItemPrice * sh.Quantity) DESC) AS OrderTotalRank,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(sh.ShipItemPrice * sh.Quantity) DESC) AS DenseRank
FROM Clients AS c JOIN Shipments AS s 
    ON c.ClientID = s.ClientID
    JOIN ShipItems AS sh
    ON s.ShipmentID = sh.ShipmentID
```

When I run the code I get this error:

> Column 'Shipments.ShipmentOrderDate' is invalid in the select list
>   because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the
>   GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 1):

You need a `GROUP BY` because you have aggregation functions in the `SELECT`.  These are separate from the window functions that you are also using:

```
SELECT ShipmentOrderDate, EmailAddress,
       SUM(sh.ShipItemPrice * sh.Quantity) AS OrderTotalRank,
       RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(sh.ShipItemPrice * sh.Quantity) DESC) AS OrderTotalRank,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(sh.ShipItemPrice * sh.Quantity) DESC) AS DenseRank
FROM Clients c JOIN
     Shipments s 
     ON c.ClientID = s.ClientID JOIN
     ShipItems sh
     ON s.ShipmentID = sh.ShipmentID
GROUP BY ShipmentOrderDate, EmailAddress;
```

Comment: Why is a GROUP BY needed here? I thought that was the issue but wasn't sure that one was needed